# Distribution of $f(X)X$ when $X$ is Uniform?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Suppose that $f$ is the probability density function of a probability measure $P$ which is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Suppose X is a uniform random variable on the interval $[0, 1]$. Is it possible to characterize the distribution of the random variable $Y := f(X) X$?

One example: suppose that $P$ is the uniform law on $[0, 1/t]$, $t \ge 1$. Then $Y$ is $0$ with probability $1-1/t$ and otherwise it is $tZ$ where $Z$ is distributed according to $P$.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrive at your conclusion from the given (in the last paragraph)?

Comment: When $P$ is uniform on $[0, 1/t]$ and $Y = f(X) X$, then note that $f = t \mathbb{I}_{[0, 1/t]}$. Thus, we have $Y = t X$ if $X \in [0, 1/t]$ and otherwise it is 0. We can see that the conditional random variable, $X \mid X \leq 1/t$ is a uniform on $[0, 1/t]$, hence the equivalence.